# Overflow-x IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, overflow, internet-explorer-6

How would I go about making IE6/7 acknowledge overflow properties?

My website works fine in IE 8+ but for some reason IE6/7 ignore the overflow property so a horizontal scrollbar is created and breaks the layout.

Website: http://jshjohnson.com

Comment: Something else seems to be going on. IE6 and IE7 should have no trouble with `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` considering they pioneered those properties.

Comment: Any ideas on what it might be then?

Comment: there are numerous problems with **IE6/7**. For exemple `<div class="fullwidth">...</div>` is not floated while it's childs such as `<div id="leeds">...</div>` are floated (doesn't matter to which side). IE interprets this block very bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this and try to write this code in conditional css for ie

```
html {overflow-x:hidden}
```